# Remove duplicate records by first name and last name combined

Tags: ms-access, vba, duplicates

Let's have a table with the following data:

```
ID         FirstName        LastName
1          jj               ff
2          jj               hh
3          jj               ff
```

I want to delete the duplicated records only by first name and last name combined. So, the output I want should be:

```
ID         FirstName        LastName
1          jj               ff
2          jj               hh
```

How to achieve this task?

**EDIT**

Just to illustrate more about my problem. My table contains ID field as a primary key. Therefor, the duplicated records in my case by the First Name and LastName only, that means ID not mandatory to be duplicated, as my table would never have duplicated ID. So, The delete duplicated records that I want is a bit different from the traditional delete methods which consider deleting rows when the whole row fields are duplicated.

Comment: I really wondering what makes a question of two  lines to be bored ? I even illustrated my needs by simple and clear example. Some people are good just in down-voting. !!

Comment: I am **not** the one who down voted.  I only offer some insight, so no offense is intended.  Deleting duplicate records in a relational (i.e. SQL) database is considered very basic for many experienced database programmers.  There are many website and video tutorials about how to do this, so I guess that others may perceive a lack of research.  The [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page suggests "Searching and researching" and the tradition is that you should share what you have tried.  There is no indication of any research or attempted solution in your question.

Comment: C Perkins, you may right in a part of the OP. However, my table contains ID field as a primary key. Therefor, the duplicated records in my case by the First Name and LastName only, that means ID not mandatory to be duplicated,  as my table would never has duplicated ID. So, The delete duplicated records  that I want  is a bit different from the traditional delete methods which consider deleting rows when the whole  row fields are duplicated. And to be honest, I haven't find a code that fill my bill  as the one  I found in the accepted answer here.

Comment: I'm glad that you got code which worked for you, but in most properly normalized tables the ID field is usually the primary key and also never duplicated.  Your case is not unusual.  All one must do is apply a basic pattern to only a couple fields and essentially ignore the other fields.  Much of programming is about following a pattern where particular details might be different.

Comment: C Perkins, maybe it was not unusual, but at least it was out of my programming abilities as I'm not good familiar with SQL

Comment: Remember, the only reason I commented was to help you realize why others down voted... and now why the question was *put on hold as too broad*.  Stack Overflow has traditionally been for focused question, not meant to be tutorials nor a code-writing service for those not familiar with a particular language.  I sympathize with you as you learn SQL, but not being familiar with SQL is not sufficient to avoid being voted down. The preferred way to research fundamentals is to find tutorials.  If you were very new to SO I wouldn't say all this, but you have high enough reputation to understand this.

Comment: @FSm - more information on how to phrase a question is available in "[ask]" and further information about **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also handy tips from the sites' top user [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table name is tblStudents, use this:

```
DELETE 
FROM tblStudents t1
WHERE t1.ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MIN(t2.ID)
FROM tblStudents t2
WHERE t1.FirstName =  t2.FirstName
AND t1.LastName =  t2.LastName
)
```

Answer (score 2):

My knowledge of Access' dialect of SQL is not great, but perhaps

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(t2.ID) FROM table t2
  GROUP BY t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
)
```

The inner statement selects the first ID for each first/last name combination (1, 2).  Then delete everything that is not in that list (3).

EDIT: Changed FIRST() to MIN()

Comment: I tried it, but error in syntax appeared

Comment: ...and the error said what?

Comment: `Syntax error in query expression  ID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(t2.ID) FROM table t2
  GROUP BY t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
) `

Comment: Show EXACTLY what you are typing in.  I tried it in Access 2003 with a table exactly like yours and it works fine.

Comment: I typed `DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(t2.ID) FROM table t2
  GROUP BY t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
);`
I'm using access 2016

Comment: You need `DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT MIN(t2.ID) FROM ***Students*** t2 GROUP BY t2.FirstName, t2.LastName )`, you didn't replace the second table name.

Comment: Now, I got error said `query must have at least one destination field`